# Download S3 file to docker image in EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3

I have an elastic beanstalk environment with permissions to a certain bucket. I want to download a few files from that bucket when my docker container is building (when deployed to EBS). I tried WGET but it failed bc it wasn't authorized. The EBS app has an authorized IAM profile...

## setup file

> ENV MYFILE /usr/src/app/filetest
>   RUN wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_test_bucket/test_test/filetest -O
>   /usr/src/app/filetest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install `aws-cli` in your docker image and configure `aws credentails` in image and the use `aws s3 cli` commands to download the file from S3 to your docker image.

Comment: this sounds very dangerous! isn't there a way whitelisting IPs?

Comment: I don't think its a easy option. and this isn't very dangerous if you have all the security in place.

Comment: example plz... and what do you mean by "all the security in place"?

Comment: @CpILL I meant, that you have configured security groups properly in AWS for your application.